# How to make assemblies from multiple objects?

Tags: constraints

I am working on a project were I need to render a product with multiple parts.
Each part is a separate object generate in Fusion 360 and imported in Blender as a .obj file

Now, I need to assemble all these components into a product but I don't know how to do it. Working with rotation and translation is a way but quite messy and complicated. There is no way to be sure of the right orientation or placement.

Here is a more detailed explanation on my problem.
I need to insert the part on the right (called shaft) onto the part on the left (called hole). 
There is not need to have mouvment between them, only a static position.

[image]

What I did so far is the following:

- set the origin of the shaft (by selecting the vertex of the surface that would be in contact, then snap cursor to selection, then origin to cursor)
- place the cursor onto the hole (by selecting the vertex of the hole and snap to selection)
- snap the shaft to the cursor

That is almost working. The shaft moves, locates well at the cursor position but...the orientation is not correct.

[image]

I am sure this process is the simplest and the most convenient to archive what I need but I don't get why the shaft doesn't get the proper alignment.

Comment: I think that it should be noted that Blender was designed with animators and modellers in mind, so it's inherently different from engineering CAD software. You'd probably want to parent an empty axis in the middle of the hole to the hole (that way if the hole moves, so does the axis), and then parent the shaft to the axis. You can use origin snapping to get it in the right spot.

Comment: Thanks I'll try your method.
Blender is not a CAD software but still users needs to be able to put objects at precise place I assume

Comment: I have tried the snap tool but for some reason the cursor is not well orientated. Geometries are actually snapping but not the angle I want because of the cursor orientation. Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, I'll write out a full answer, just give me a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the hole object and the shaft object (shown below). I've taken the opportunity to rotate the hole from the global XYZ axes just in case that's what you're dealing with.

[image]

The first thing you want to do is to add an empty axis along the desired rotational axis of the shaft. If the shaft is symmetrical and aligned with the global axes, select the shaft, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* to move the 3D Cursor to the shaft origin, and add <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Empty > Plain Axis.* You'll then want to parent the shaft to the *Plain Axis*.

That step is to allow you to rotate the shaft about its local X, Y or Z-axis. Long story short, if you try to spin an object around an axis that's not the global axis, things get messy. In the case of your shaft not being aligned to any of the XYZ axes, you'll have to first rotate the shaft so that the rotational axis does align with one of them, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Rotation*. Then you can add the empty as I showed above.

[image]

Next, go to the hole. Select all the vertices/edges that make up the hole, press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill it in, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> *> Poke Faces.* What this step will do is create a face with a normal that matches the desired rotational axis, and adds a vertex in the middle of it that we can use to snap the *Plain Axis* to.

[image]

Next, enable *Vertex Snapping* making sure you enable *Align Rotation to Target*. Grab the *Plain Axis*, and snap it to the vertex we made in the hole earlier.

[image]
[image]

Now you can delete the vertex from the hole, and rotate the shaft by rotating the shaft object, leave the *Plain Axis* alone.

[image]

**EDIT: from additional info**

If you don't need to rotate the shaft, you don't need to use the *Plain Axis.* Fill in the hole face, and poke it as I showed above. Then, if you grab the shaft using *Vertex Snapping*, *Snap with Active Element* and *Align Rotation to Target*, you can move it onto the hole and it will automatically align itself for you. Then you can delete the extra vertex from poking the face.

From there, if you need the shaft to be further in/out of the whole, use <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to slide it in/out.

[image]

Comment: Look good although I don't need to rotate the shaft but only position it properly.
Is there a way to simplify the workflow ?

Comment: Looking at the edit to your question, are you using Shift+S > Selection to Cursor, or moving the shaft and using vertex snapping? If you're using the latter, look at the *Snap to* menu in my answer, and instead of enabling *Align Rotation to Target*, disable it. Using Shift+S > Selection to Cursor shouldn't be rotating the shaft, not from my experience at least.

Comment: I am using SHIFT + S to snap the origin of the shaft to the cursor I placed at the suitable position of the hole.

Comment: Try selecting your shaft and pressing Ctrl+A > Apply Rotation. The snapping should work after that. I'm still unsure why the snapping is causing the shaft to rotate...it really should only be moving it, but this should be a suitable workaround

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't help.
is that so difficult for Blender to make two geometries snapping each other...
Basic feature imo

Comment: Ok, well in that case, change the *Transform Pivot Point* to *Individual Origins*, then use G to move the shaft and snap it to the vertex you used to move the 3D Cursor to...I can't find anything on Snap to Cursor rotating the object

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thanks for trying to help me but I can't imagine why when I ask Blender to snap to a surface it is not able to change orientation. Maybe it's something related to the geometry orientation itself

Comment: Wait...is the shaft already aligned to the hole (as it is in the first image in your post), or is it starting off vertical and not aligned as it is in the second image?

Comment: The shaft starts randomly in the workspace. It's actually vertical and needs to be correctly aligned to the hole geometry

Comment: Ok, I added an edit to the answer. You could use the method I had described earlier, but you won't need to use the whole *Plain Axis* part of it.

Comment: When I create the fill surface, I don't get a point but a mess.
I am between depressed and pissed that such a basic move cannot be made with that software. Really ?

Comment: Once again...different software, different purposes, different workflows. I can attest to that as a current engineering undergrad student...Did you select only the edge loop around the hole? When you fill in that face, you'll get a single ngon that you then have to poke to add the extra vertex.

Comment: When I select the edge around the hole and fill, I get edges everywhere inside de filled surface.

Comment: Are you filling the edges by pressing F in edit mode?

Comment: yes I am going just that

Comment: Do you have Discord? My username is stphnl329#8530, it sounds like having direct communication might be better here

Comment: No sorry, I don't have Discord sadly :/

Comment: In that case...you could also manually rotate the shaft. I presume that you know the angles that the holes are at? You could use the Item sidebar or by pressing R, X/Y/Z, then typing in the angle

Comment: That is what I wanted to avoid...
But no choice I guess

Comment: One step at a time I guess...too many issues arising to troubleshoot over text :/